# using two contextual filters

Tags: views

Hey guys I have been troubled for quite some time on this issue, I know there is probably one straight forward solution but from all the tutorials I have seen and info on drupal, I have not solved my problem.

I need to have a block that gets results from blog content types with same taxonomy term and same 'source' field value, how would I get into doing this? I can only get the taxonomy with 'has taxonomy term ID' contextual filter, but cant get the other one to show up correctly.

Comment: I think I understand your question correctly.  If not it may be worth rewriting with more detail.  Have you got the relationship built for the 'source' field value.  ? I take it this field is not in your Taxonomy, so will need to linked in 'Relationships'.

Comment: also can you see the queries you're building.  I find this a great help .  you can do this at admin/structure/views/settings